# Hyperbolic sin and cos of an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math, mpmath

I'm trying to define some function for an eady stream function model as shown in the next line:

```
# Geometry of the wave / domain / mean state:
Lx = 3800                          # Zonal Wavelength in km
H = 10000                          # tropopause height in meters
Shear = 30/H                       # shear in sec^-1

k = 2*np.pi/(Lx*1000)              # wavenumber (zonal)
l = np.pi/3.e6                     # meridional wavenumber in 1/m

# Constants:
cor = 2*(7.292e-5)*np.sin(np.pi/4) # Coriolis parameter
bv2 = 1.e-4                        # buoyancy frequency squared
sigma = 2.e-6                      # static stability parameter
R = 287                            # gas constant

# Grid points on which fields are computed:
xx = np.linspace(0,1.5*Lx,151)     # gridpoints in x
yy = np.linspace( -1500,1500,101)  # gridpoints in y
zz = np.linspace(0,H,51)           # gridpoints in z

# Set array for grid system in x, y, and z
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(xx*1000, yy*1000, zz)

# Define coefficients for the model
mu2 = ((bv2*(H**2))/cor**2)*(k**2 + l**2)
mu = np.sqrt(mu2)
c = (Shear*H/2) + ((Shear*H)/mu)*np.sqrt((mu/2 - coth(mu/2))*(mu/2 - tanh(mu/2)))
# Note: try switching this to (Shear*H/2) - (Shear*H/mu)*...

ci = np.imag(c)
cr = np.real(c)
t = 0*np.pi/(10*cr*k)

A = 2.e7                     # streamfunction amplitude (arbitrary)
B = -A*Shear*H/(mu*c)
Psi_z = A*cosh(mu*z/H) + B*sinh(mu*z/H)
```

I noticed that I'm getting an error when it comes to taking the hyperbolic sin and cos of the array with the following message:

```
TypeError: cannot create mpf from array (mu*z/H) for both sin and cos.
```

I've never encountered this error message before, so I'm not familiar enough to try and figure out an approach to this error.

Comment: What do you mean by `array`?  If you want real help, provide real data!

Comment: Show all the relevant imports and variable definitions.

Comment: @hpaulj Just updated the question, completely forgot to add what array meant while editing the question. Thank you!

Comment: Why  are you trying to use `mpmath` functions on `numpy` arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj Just following what my professor did in his coding on Matlab which I'm trying to re-write in python.

Comment: `numpy` has `cosh` and `sinh` functions.

Comment: @hpaulj  Yes, but I noticed that NumPy doesn't have coth (which I use to calculate c), so then I switched to mpmath. But now that I switched from using mpmath to NumPy for my sine and cosine, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: But `coth(x)` is simply `1 / tanh(x)`, and NumPy _does_ have `tanh`.